# Calling static function of generic type

Tags: typescript

Imagine a function that operates on generic types:

```
protected foo<T>(abc: any): T{
    //[...]
    let x : T = T.fromString(xyz);
    //[...]
}
```

`fromString(xyz: string)` is a static function that somehow converts string to `T`.

Of course it doesn't work now, because T is type not value. But if I knew that every class that will be in place of `T` will have `fromString` method implemented, how can I make this work correctly?

I thought about creating interface:

```
export interface DtoSchema {
    fromString<T>(data:any) : T;
}
```

And implementing it in class:

```
export class ColumnDTO implements DtoSchema {
    //[...]
    static fromString<T extends DtoSchema>(data: any): T {
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        let result = new ColumnDTO();
        result.init(data);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I've exerimented with that a bit, but I can't make it work. Here is the last error I've encountered:

> Type 'ColumnDTO' is not assignable to type 'T'

Am I trying to do it correctly? How would you fix it?

Comment: Problem will be at run time, there will be nothing for JS to use to grab that method from (types are some syntactic sugar that TypeScript adds and is completely stripped when compiling). Maybe you can just have a function passed that is the `fromString` method. It will be up to the caller to statically use the type's static `fromString` method. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

This simply answers the question you asked.

> `Type 'ColumnDTO' is not assignable to type 'T'`

Your simplified code showing the error:

```
interface DtoSchema { }
export class ColumnDTO {
    static fromString<T extends DtoSchema>(data: any): T {
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        let result = new ColumnDTO();
        result.init(data);
        return result; // ERROR: Type 'ColumnDTO' is not assignable to type 'T'
    }
    init(data: any) {
    }
}
```

## Fix

Fix the return type annotation to match what you are returning:

```
interface DtoSchema { } 
export class ColumnDTO {
    static fromString<T extends DtoSchema>(data: any): ColumnDTO { // FIX!
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        let result = new ColumnDTO();
        result.init(data);
        return result; // No error!
    }
    init(data: any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you removed content of DtoSchema interface on purpose? I mean: DtoSchema now doesn't indicate that there will be such method like `fromString`. Is it OK to do it that way?

Comment: Because now when I want to call `fromString` from T (that way: `(T as DtoSchema).fromString(item)`), compiler says that there is no such thing like `fromString` in `DtoSchema`. And basically it is right. DtoSchema doesn't have any `fromString` method